# Where can I download english dictionary database in a text format?

Tags: dictionary

I need to read the text file for a word and return its meaning. Any other file format will also work.

Comment: I've wrote a web clawler for all famous online dictionaries (Oxford, Longman, Cambridge, Webster, and Collins) you can use this to make your datset. https://github.com/kiasar/Dictionary_crawler

Comment: I've found free dictionary database:  https://github.com/eddydn/DictionaryDatabase

Comment: @Peyman there may be issues with using something like that for production due to copyright issues. It is well known that dictionaries will sometimes create a fake word that they can use to identify unauthorized use. User beware.

Answer (score 69):

The [Gutenberg Project hosts Webster's Unabridged English Dictionary](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29765) plus many other public domain literary works. Actually it looks like they've got several versions of the dictionary hosted with copyright from different years. The one I linked has a 2009 copyright. You may want to poke around the site and investigate the different versions of Webster's dictionary.

Comment: '09 cleaned-up transcript of the 1913 version, apparently the OCR wasn't completely clean.  There are a total of 15 versions on the site.

Comment: This dictionary doesn't include the plural forms of the words, but they can be included with the Inflect module for python 3.

Answer (score 57):

user1247808 has a good link with: wget -c

http://www.androidtech.com/downloads/wordnet20-from-prolog-all-3.zip

If that isn't enough words for you:

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/enwiktionary-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz (updated url from Michael Kropat's suggestion)

Although that file name changes, you'll want to find the latest ... that turns out just to be a big (very big) text file.

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/

Comment: You can always download the latest wiktionary from http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/enwiktionary-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz

Comment: androidtech/wordnet20 is in SQL format not txt.

Comment: Please note: The syntax in the wordnet20 has a deprecated TYPE=* in the .sql file. Run `sed -i 's/TYPE=/ENGINE=/g' wordnet20-from-prolog-all-3.sql` to replace the deprecated syntax before running it against a 5.0+ version of MySQL

Comment: no simple txt file containing all English words?

Answer (score 31):

I dont know if its too late, but i thought it would help someone else.

I wanted the same badly...found it eventually.

Maybe its not perfect,but to me its adequate(for my little dictionary app).

http://www.androidtech.com/downloads/wordnet20-from-prolog-all-3.zip

Its not a dump file, but a MYSQL .sql script file

The words are in WN_SYNSET table and the glossary/meaning in the WN_GLOSS table

Comment: What license is this under?

Comment: I'm not sure also, but at http://www.androidtech.com/html/downloads.php there is `Here are some files related to natural language and chatterbot projects that we are making available to the public`

Comment: MySQL users: the create table statements use the now removed TYPE option. Run this on the file `sed -i 's/TYPE=MyISAM/ENGINE=MyISAM/g' filename.sql` to get it working in the latest MySQL

Answer (score 16):

Check if these free resources fit your need -

- [FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/source.html) - dictionary source is a single plain text file.
- ObjectGraph has a [SQL Server database version](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2005/01/20/wordnet-20-almost-ready/) of the [WordNet
  lexical database](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download/current-version) from Princeton University

Comment: FOLDOC (Free On-line Dictionary of Computing) appears to be a dictionary of computing terms/names only. It might be useful for some, but it's not a general purpose dictionary you can look up most words in.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté your link is also dead now