# C: String Spell Checker Guidance

Tags: c, spell-checking

I have a homework assignment in my C programming class that requires me to have a program open a text file, process each word separately, and assume that each word is separated by some white space and that there are no multi-line words, or words that contain a hyphen, and then compare each of the words to a dictionary file to see if they are valid English words. After it has checked, it needs to output what the misspelled words are, in their correct form. I'm not looking for someone to do this entirely for me, but rather, I'd like some guidance as to where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell you where to start without knowing how much you know. Do you know how to open a text file, and read data from it? Do you know how to store data in a data structure like an array? Do you have an exact description of the problem?

"Output what the misspelled words are, in their correct form" is a bit vague; it's impossible in general to tell what word you meant if a word is misspelled, instead you can only offer suggestions that are close to the given word. Has your instructor mentioned what kind of distance metric you are supposed to use for finding words that are close to the misspelled words? Have they talked about what kind of data structures you are supposed to be using?

Generally, the best way to start is to start simply, and then refine you program as you go. You can first start by just reading in the input file, breaking it up into words, and then print those words out. That lets you test that your ability to read the file in and break it into words works, without having to worry about the other parts.

Then add something that reads in the dictionary. It should probably add each entry into an array. Do you know if the dictionary is sorted to begin with? If so, that will help later; if not, you will probably want to sort your array after reading it in (or keep it sorted as you add new elements).

Then change your code so that the part that reads in the input file looks through the dictionary array to see if a word is in it. If it is, it's spelled correctly. If not, you can add it to an output array, or just print it out immediately. You can start by just iterating through every element of the dictionary and comparing the current word to it. Once you have that working, it would be more efficient to do a binary search of the dictionary, rather than comparing words one by one; but a general rule of thumb is to get it working first, then make it more efficient.

Now you have something that finds all of the misspelled words. The last step is to offer suggestions for corrections. This is a little bit more difficult, and there are many possible ways to do this. I would check with your instructor how they meant for you to do this, because it's not exactly an introductory problem. But if you want some suggestions, see [this answer for a question about how to implement a spelling checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker).

Answer (score 0):

one google a word dictionary txt format,
check this thread:
[Where can I download english dictionary database in a text format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441975/where-can-i-download-english-dictionary-database-in-a-text-fomat)
2- scan open the txt file that has your words,
read the first word
create a function that has as parameter a string (array of char) that take the word read from the txt and comapre it to each word in the dictionary until it find a match or end of file