# Sql database of english dictionary

Tags: sql, database, dictionary

I was making a crossword generator.So, i need open source a sql database of english dictionary(with meanings,synonyms,word type) for my software.Where can I find it??

Comment: try http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine this question will be closed, but this question has flat file, as well as SQL server example database reccomendations.

[Where can I download english dictionary database in a text format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441975/where-can-i-download-english-dictionary-database-in-a-text-fomat)