# How to check a string against the Windows dictionary?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, spell-checking

How can you check if a certain string is in the Windows dictionary?

Or, in other words, how to you grab the entirety of the Windows dictionary, so you can set a new dictionary to have that content?

Comment: Are you talking about a spell-check dictionary of some sort?

Comment: Yes I am! As in for spell checking purposes.

Comment: Are you sure there is a spell check dictionary in Windows? I know there is one for MS Office, and there is one for Internet Explorer with version 10 and later, but is this part of Windows, or part of those apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 there is a [Spelling Checking API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that can be consumed from VB.Net via COM.

There is a link to the Microsoft Word Dictionary format (.dic file) listed on [Wotsit.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20120502054739/http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?page=6&fc=0&search=&al=), unfortunately the site is currently unavailable (the link provided is via the Wayback machine).

Microsoft provide a [Common Speller API (CSAPI) for Office spell checking](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262605), however it appears to require a third party dictionary.

Merriam-Webster provide an online [Dictionary API](http://www.dictionaryapi.com/) which is free for non-commercial use.

[Microsoft Small Basic](http://smallbasic.com/) provides a [Dictionary API](http://www.smallbasic.com/doc/?id=5&language=) which connects to an online service and can be consumed from VB.Net, simply import the SmallBasicLibrary.dll.

```
Imports Microsoft.SmallBasic.Library

Module MyModule

    Sub Main()
        Dim definition = Dictionary.GetDefinition("vowel")
        ' A string is returned if the word exists in the dictionary
        Console.WriteLine(CStr(definition))
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks! Does that also work when using forms? Or is there different expression?

Comment: Also, is there a way of checking whether a word is in this dictionary?

Comment: The Small Basic Dictionary is environment agnostic, it will work in WPF, WinForms, command line etc.

Comment: The Small Basic Dictionary will not return a description if the word is not in the dictionary. You may also want to take a look at the Merriam-Webster Dictionary API (& others) which appears to have more sophisticated functionality.

Comment: No problem, yet another option, which might be better for performance, would be to download an open source dictionary database, see SO "Where can I download English dictionary database in a text format?" http://stackoverflow.com/q/6441975/2012417

Comment: Where can you download the SmallBasicLibrary.dll file? Every time I try to enter the code you've written it says that there's a problem:

Comment: Warning    1 Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.SmallBasic.Library' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Module1.vb 1 9 ConsoleApplication1
_

Comment: To get the SmallBasicLibrary.dll you need to install Small Basic (which is pretty small)

Comment: I did that, where is the .dll located?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, but go to the command prompt, type "cd \" to go to the root, and then type "dir SmallBasicLibrary.dll /s" to find it.

Comment: OK, found it, how do you install it?

Comment: Right click your project and select Add References, then select the location of the library

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. Last question: how do you check whether a definition is found or not (as in, to determine if it's in the dictionary)?

Comment: If the word is found in the dictionary the length of the returned definition string will be greater than zero.