# Look up word meaning programmatically and print it to file

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I came up with an idea to improve my vocabulary.The idea is to have large number of the most common english words in a file.
I would then write a program that displays the words on the screen one at a time.If i recognize the word,I press the DOWN key to
move to the next word,otherwise I press 'S' to save this word to a text file called Unknown.txt .

When i get finished,i will have collected all the words that i don't know their meaning.If i stop here,and go through each word manually
and seach for it's meaning with my dictionary,it will take alot of time to learn them all this way.

However,if i have a method to save the meaning of the word programatically,
i can easily open the file and learn the meaning of the words immediatly.That is what i want to acheive.

The "10kword.txt" file looks like the following:

> purchase
>   customers
>   active
>   response
>   practice
>   hardware.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void cls(void *hConsole);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *inp, *out;
    if (fopen_s(&inp, "10kWords.txt", "r")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (fopen_s(&out, "Unknown.txt", "a")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file Unknown.txt\n");
        fclose(inp);
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[100];
    void *hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    while (1) {
        //Press the down key to move to the next word
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) == -32767) {
            cls(hConsole);
            fscanf_s(inp, "%s", buf, 100);
            printf("%s", buf);
        }
        //Press S to save the word to output file
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState('S') == -32767) {
            fprintf(out, "%s\n", buf);
            //Obtain word meaning from dictionary Programatically HERE and print it to 'out'
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(inp);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}

void cls(void *hConsole)
{
    COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };    // home for the cursor 
    DWORD cCharsWritten;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD dwConSize;
    // Get the number of character cells in the current buffer. 
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi))
    {
        return;
    }
    dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
    // Fill the entire screen with blanks.
    if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole,        // Handle to console screen buffer 
        (TCHAR) ' ',     // Character to write to the buffer
        dwConSize,       // Number of cells to write 
        coordScreen,     // Coordinates of first cell 
        &cCharsWritten))// Receive number of characters written
    {
        return;
    }
    // Get the current text attribute.
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi))
    {
        return;
    }
    // Set the buffer's attributes accordingly.
    if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole,         // Handle to console screen buffer 
        csbi.wAttributes, // Character attributes to use
        dwConSize,        // Number of cells to set attribute 
        coordScreen,      // Coordinates of first cell 
        &cCharsWritten)) // Receive number of characters written
    {
        return;
    }
    // Put the cursor at its home coordinates.
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't use symbol names with leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like your variable `_Buf`). Such names are reserved for "the implementation" (i.e. the compiler and the standard library). Also don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) like `-32767`. If you want to check for a specific bit or bits use bitwise operators.

Comment: I get this warning at line 22; `main.cpp(22): warning C4473: 'fscanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz ,Actually i used fscanf,but the compiler refused to compile the code and proposed `fscan_s` so i used it,and it compiled with warnings  which i ignored.

Comment: Don't ignore warnings, they are the compilers way of saying you do something wrong or dangerous. You get the warning because you don't provide enough arguments to the function, and that will lead to *undefined behavior*. You should [read a `fscanf_s` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx).

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking. I can see a number of errors in your code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is it you don't understand? The question is clear enough.As for the code,it compiles fine without  warnings.

Comment: I don't understand what you want from us. The question is not clear. The only question in the text is, "Can someone help me out with this one?" What exactly do you want? And there are errors in the code. The fact that it compiles does not mean that it is correct. Your use of `GetAsyncKeyState` is badly wrong, for instance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan then I will edit the question later today.

Comment: Why go through the trouble of writing a program to make a Web API call when you can just download a dictionary with definitions and store it on your hard drive? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441975/where-can-i-download-english-dictionary-database-in-a-text-fomat, for example.

Comment: @JimMischel I already have a dictionary installed,but i don't want to search the words my self.I want the meanings to be stored along-side the words that i don't know their meanings when i press 'S'.That way,i open the file called Unknown.txt and start learning immediately.

Comment: I don't see where having the file on disk precludes you from doing what you want. Just have your program look up the meaning in the dictionary on disk rather than calling the Web API.

Comment: @JimMischel That's part of my question.How do i have my program look up the meaning in the dictionary on disk?

Comment: That rather depends on the format of the dictionary. You can sequentially search a text file. Or you can store it in a database, or you can load the whole thing into an in-memory data structure and search that, whether it's an array of words with definitions or a hash map or whatever.

Comment: The file `"10kword.txt"` seems to be a list of English words. It's not a dictionary, but it can be used for spell check. For example you type in "blu", and the program suggests "blue". If you want an actual dictionary I think @Tmayto has a solution to look up words online. You could do an offline version of it, but it would need a large dictionary database.

Comment: What's up with all the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though what you are looking for is a dictionary API that you can send a request to a server and get a response. A quick [google search](https://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dictionary%20api) shows there are quite a lot. In addition to this you will also need a couple extra libraries for C to make the HTTP requests, such as  [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), and a way to parse JSON or XML From [this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c) you have an example of how to use it, and from there you can use it to send requests to Merriam's API.

[Here's another good API](https://glosbe.com/a-api).

This one's definitely an open ended question but hopefully I've pointed you in the right direction.

Here's some sample code [from the curl website](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) showing how to use Curl to do a get http request:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};

static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

  mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(mem->memory == NULL) {
    /* out of memory! */ 
    printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
    return 0;
  }

  memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

  return realsize;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl_handle;
  CURLcode res;

  struct MemoryStruct chunk;

  chunk.memory = malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */ 
  chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */ 

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* init the curl session */ 
  curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

  /* specify URL to get */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/overflow?key=<YOUR KEY GOES HERE>");

  /* send all data to this function  */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

  /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

  /* some servers don't like requests that are made without a user-agent
     field, so we provide one */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

  /* get it! */ 
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

  /* check for errors */ 
  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
  }
  else {
    /*
     * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
     * bytes big and contains the remote file.
     *
     * Do something nice with it!
     */ 

    printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (long)chunk.size);
  }

  /* cleanup curl stuff */ 
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

  free(chunk.memory);

  /* we're done with libcurl, so clean it up */ 
  curl_global_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

This example would then print the definition of overflow as an XML file to memory.

Good luck!

Comment: Don't you think this is C++ ??

Comment: Whoops I got the tag wrong. Give me a couple minutes and I'll update my answer for C

Comment: There you go. Sorry for the wait I forgot to comment that it was updated. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your program: you use `fscanf_s` incorrectly.  You should pass the size of the destination buffer as an `rsize_t` or a `size_t`, not an `int`.  There is a good chance `int` and `size_t` do not have the same size on your system, so you are invoking undefined behavior.  Fix the code this way:

```
fscanf_s(inp, "%s", buf, (size_t)100);
```

You should also check the return value of `fscanf_s` to verify if it did parse a word from the input file.  You might also want to specify a maximum number of characters to scan for a word to avoid `fscanf_s` default behavior that will terminate the program if the word typed is too long.  Do this with:

```
fscanf_s(inp, "%99s", buf, (size_t)100);
```

Comment: Thank you chqrlie for your valuable programming advices.But how does fhat answer my question?

Comment: @machine_1: Actually, I did not really see a question in your post... I pointed to some errors in the code that could explain some problems... What are you asking exactly?

Comment: How do i get meanings of the words programatically.That is my question.