# Creating Dictionary (English dictionary ) with python

Tags: python

Recently I made a English word definition dictionary as described in a course in udemy.

They have used a  **data.json** file which contains a **dictionary** inside it with all the words and their meaning as key value pair, so it was an easy task.

Are there some more ways to create dictionary and what data to use, like if I don't have a dictionary (key value pair).

Any ideas ??

Comment: If you don't have key/value pairs, then perhaps a dictionary isn't the right choice for your data structure.  Maybe some other structure, like a list, would work better?

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? Perhaps have a read of the docs regarding dictionaries in Python, and come back if you need clarification - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: by dictionary  I mean meanings and definition of words and the bold **dictionary** is the data structure .

Comment: I'm still not sure how to answer your question. It sounds a bit like this one, which was closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441975/where-can-i-download-english-dictionary-database-in-a-text-format

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to get the data? Or how to read in data that you already have? Or how to set up an organisation that will research and collate all known words in your chosen language, and publish this new dictionary as a Python data structure? Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

A python dictionary would definitely be the easiest way to store word : definitions (key-value pairs), and you can import from or export to a json file as well. Of course, there are other structures like lists, but they are far less optimal. A pandas dataframe could work and would be useful if you wanted to have multiple entries with the same key but different definitions: e.g. key + def 1, key + def 2, key + def 3, since much like an excel sheet, each entry could be its own row which are then sorted based on key.